# KDE input not allowing accented characters

Tags: kde, locale

Most KDE applications won't accept accented characters, showing instead ���.
This happens in Kate, Konsole and Dolphin (although not in Konqueror; nor in Chrome, LibreOffice, etc).

The fonts support accented characters as I can past a test sample (such as "áááÀ���") and is shown correctly.

```
> locale
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_PT.utf8
LC_TIME=pt_PT.utf8
LC_COLLATE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=pt_PT.utf8
LC_NAME=pt_PT.utf8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_PT.utf8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_PT.utf8
LC_ALL=
```

**EDIT (after replies) :**

I'm using Debian 9.4 (Stretch) with KDE Framework v.5.28.

- kde-l10n-pt package is installed
- System Settings > Regional Settings > Language is set to "American English" (I prefer to see messages and dialogues in English)

I added a few locale's while trying to fix this issue:

```
>locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
portuguese
POSIX
pt_PT
pt_PT@euro
pt_PT.iso88591
pt_PT.iso885915@euro
pt_PT.utf8
```

And with `dpkg-reconfigure locales` I set the language to "en_US.UTF-8 ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently this is a bug in qt/kde.
Details in the [KDE bug tracker](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=356214) and [QT bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49438)

As a workaround, the suggestion is to install ibus:

```
apt-get install ibus ibus-qt4 ibus-gtk3 ibus-gtk
```

(I installed all 4 packages, so I'm not sure if they are all necessary)

**Don't forget to logout and in again.**

Answer (score 0):

You should check why you have "en_US" in the LANGUAGE variable. That might be causing some trouble.

I don't know which distribution or KDE version you are using (you should add that information to your question), but you can set locale settings in KDE:

Go to **System Settings**, you should find the **Regional Settings**, and select the **Language** you want there (might need to download a l10n package, like `kde-l10n-pt`). If you want the applications also in you language you should download the `language-pack-kde-pt`

Also, make sure you have the locale you want as default.

Verify with `locale -a` the installed ones, and if using a Debian based distribution (Ubuntu for ex.), set the default locale with:

`dpkg-reconfigure locales`

And select all the UTF8 locales you want and the Default for the system settings.

Comment: Thanks @Leo.  I should have been more thorough in the description of my previous steps to resolve this issue. I hope my edits correct that.

Comment: I don't know which characters you are trying to see, but for the record, I'm seeing the square with the question marks too in your post. Here is the screenshot: https://screenshots.firefox.com/8eM2wjthzpK6b2KZ/unix.stackexchange.com
I'm using `en_US.UTF-8` and `es_AR.UTF-8`.
As I said above, using en_US (plain, no utf8) as LANGUAGE, might be your issue. You could try setting the 3 variables in .bashrc:

`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
`export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: "áááÀ���"
The squares with the question mark are supposed to be "áááÀ", but in Kate or Konsole they turn into that.
I tried `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8;`. Is this supposed to work by just typing and enter? Because it didn't...
Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: No. It might not work if you just type it. You should place it in ~/.bashrc , logout & login for it to work reliably. I see the áááÀ alright in my konsole. Does `locale` still show `LANGUAGE=en_US`?

Comment: That didn't work. :(